# How to redirect to different page after form is submitted using header()?

Tags: php

I've looked at lots of answers to redirect to a different page after submitting a form, but haven't been able to get it to work thus far, probably because I have no idea where to actually put the code. Can anyone help? The rest of this code is working fine, i just need to know where to place header():

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


//connects to database, checks username & password against database to see is user exists
if($username && $password)
{
include ("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows !==0)
  {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
       $dbusername = $row['username'];
       $dbpassword = $row['password'];
   }
   //if username and password are correct
   if($username==$dbusername&&md5($password)==$dbpassword)
   {
       echo "You are logged in. <a href='main.php'>Continue to site.</a>";
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   }
   //if password is incorrect
   else
        echo "Your password is incorrect.";
   }
   //if username is incorrect
   else
        die("Username does not exist.");
  }
  //if no information is submitted
  else
        die("Please enter your login details.");

//prevents errors from displaying on page
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

I also need to know where it goes for this page:

```
<?php
//Check if register button was pressed
$button = $_POST['button'];

//if button was pressed,
if ($button)
{
//get data from form,
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$retype_password = $_POST['retype_password'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
}

//check if all information has been entered,
if ($username && $password && $retype_password && $first_name && $last_name)
{
//check if password and retype_password are the same
if($password==$retype_password)
{
    //check if username already exists
    include("connect.php");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows == 0)
    {
        //encrypt password
        $password = md5($password);

        //sends data from form to database - creates new user
        $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$username', '$password',       '$first_name', '$last_name')");

        echo "You are now registered. <a href='main.php'>Continue to site.</a>";
    }
    else
        echo "Username is unavailable.";
}
else
    echo "Password did not match.";         
}

//prevents errors from displaying on page
error_reporting(0);

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($username==$dbusername&&md5($password)==$dbpassword)
   {

       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;   

   }
```

Comment: You cannot print content before a `header()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it once the job is done : that is after

```
//echo "You are logged in. <a href='main.php'>Continue to site.</a>";
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('Location: your url');
exit;
```

Don't forget the "exit" or what follow will be executed.

That said, you cannot echo something before a doing redirection, that's logical because the echo can't be seen.

So, either you do not echo :

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('Location: your url');
exit;
```

Or you do a HTML (or javascript) redirection, with a 5 seconds delay:

```
echo "You are logged in. <a href='main.php'>Continue to site.</a>";
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
exit;
```

In which case you have to put it in the < head > section, to do the HTML redirection:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/main.php" />
```

---

Also

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Should be put at the beginning of the page, unless you want errors for previous lines to be shown.

BUT : error_reporting(0); should NEVER be used on a development site (and always on a production site).

You should turn on display_errors('on') and error_reporting(E_ALL) to see errors - errors are very useful for a developer.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I've made the changes to the login form, but now when i submit its just displaying the last echo ("Please enter your login details."). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, actually I made a mistake because you cannot make any "echo" before doing a header redirection. So what would you prefer : 1/ displaying a message on the screen, wait 5 secs and then redirect 2/ remove the "echo" and redirect only ? I'll edit my message after your answer.

Comment: preferably I'd just like to redirect directly to the page.